# PHP how to list all files in directory in a combobox - only file names and not with full paths

Tags: php, list, combobox

I am trying to create a form where the user can select what image should be linked to what item before he inserts it into a database.

here is the code

```
$files = glob('images/items/Done/*.jpg');
echo "<select>";
foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<option>".$file."</option>"; }
echo "</select>";
```

Everything works fine ..except I want only file names listed and not the whole path.

NOT images/items/Done/picture.jpg

BUT picture.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob('images/items/Done/*.jpg');
echo "<select>";
foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<option>".pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME)."</option>"; }
echo "</select>";
```